# How to Transfer GridView Value when click selected item to recycleview Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

[image]

I want to send item value from gridview to recycleview, anyone please help me

---

i'm sorry i can't write code here, because i'm newbie and i don't know how to write it because i'm still learn english he he he :D

here activity Gridview

```
http://pasted.co/ed5617c0
```

here activity adapter

```
http://pasted.co/966507e0
```

here layout gridview

```
http://pasted.co/e4fd8803
```

please help me solve this, thanks

Comment: You should post some code to help you better but you can use EventBus library https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Save your selected grid view value in a local database(sqlite) then populate the value in recyclerview from the local db

Comment: give me example code, sorry i'm new here

Answer (score 0):

First add the selected data to recyclerview adapter list as below:

```
mItem.add(data);
```

and then use:

```
recyclerviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

second remove data from gridview adapter list

```
mItem.remove(data);
```

and then use:

```
gridviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i don't get it, sorry bro

Comment: step1: get the data which is clicked in grid view.step2: add that data to the adaper of recyclerview. step3: remove the data from adaper of grid view. Step4: apply adaper.notifyDataSetChanged for both adater. i.e for gridview adaper and recyclerview adaper.

Comment: please post you code. so that i can edit that to do this.

Comment: u can contact me on email, here my email riverwithin@gmail.com